# detached entity passed to persist: one to one to relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an Entity Survey like this:

```
@Entity
public class SurveyData {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SURVEY_ID")
private Long Id;

@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
public Client client;

@OneToOne
@JsonManagedReference
@JoinColumn(name = "surveyresult_id")
private SurveyDataResults surveyDataResults;

private Character unit;
..and other fields
```

And another Entity the SurveyDataResults like this :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "surveydataresults")
public class SurveyDataResults {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SURVEYRESULT_ID")
private Long Id;
..and other fields
```

SurveyData gets filled from a POST form, and after that i saved, there's some calculations made with those fields and then saved on the SurveyDataResult.
When I submit the form for the first time, it gets saved on SurveyData and it holds a reference to the first SurveyDataResults, with id 1 where all the results are.
When I fill out the form for the second time with values I get an error : detached entity passed to persist:SurveyDataResults

The problem I see, is that if I fill out the form one after another, the results of the second form submitted get saved on the SurveyDataResults with ID=1. Therefore the detached entity issue,because it has already been saved once.
How do I make it that after every form submission the mapping to be accordingly ?

EDIT:

My Post Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewSurvey(@Valid SurveyData survey_data, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    long clientId = survey_data.client.getId();
    SurveyData newSurvey = surveyService.saveSurvey(survey_data);
    Long surveyId = newSurvey.getId();
    calculateService.CalculateFirst(surveyId);
    calculateService.CalculateSecond(surveyId);
    calculateService.CalculateThird(surveyId);
    =
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/user/surveys?getId=" + clientId);
}
```

And in the calculateService I save every field using .save like this :
surveyServiceResults.saveSurveyResults(surveyresults);

```
 @Service("calculateService")
public class CalculateServiceImpl implements CalculateService {
@Autowired
private SurveyDataRepository surveyDataRepository;
SurveyDataResults surveyresults = new SurveyDataResults();
@Autowired
private SurveyServiceResults surveyServiceResults;

 public void CalculateFirst(Long id){
    SurveyData survey = surveyDataRepository.findOne(id);
    Integer c=survey.getA()+survey.getB();
    surveyResults.setC(c);
    surveyServiceResults.saveSurveyResults(surveyresults);
}
 public void CalculateSecond(Long id){
    SurveyData survey = surveyDataRepository.findOne(id);
    Integer D=survey.getB()+survey.getM();
    surveyResults.setD(D);
    surveyServiceResults.saveSurveyResults(surveyresults);
}
```

Service:

```
public interface SurveyServiceResults {

public void saveSurveyResults(SurveyDataResults surveyresults);
```

}

Implementation:

```
@Service("surveyServiceResults")
```

public class SurveyServiceResultsImpl implements SurveyServiceResults {

```
@Autowired
private SurveyDataResultsRepository surveyDataResultsRepository;

@Override
public void saveSurveyResults(SurveyDataResults surveyresults) {
    surveyDataResultsRepository.save(surveyresults);
}
}
```

Repository :

```
@Repository("surveyDataResults")
public interface SurveyDataResultsRepository  extends 
JpaRepository<SurveyDataResults, Long>{}
```

This is the error I get :

```
detached entity passed to persist: com.test.test1.model.SurveyDataResults; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.test.test1.model.SurveyDataResults
```

Comment: Show us with code what you describe in words

Comment: I edited the post. Thank you

Comment: Post also the `surveyService.saveSurvey` method and `calculateService.CalculateFirst`, `calculateService.CalculateSecond`, `calculateService.CalculateThird` methods. Please provide as much info as you can, also dont forget to post the full error stacktrace, not just `detached entity passed to persist:SurveyDataResults`

Comment: I added the functions though simplified the actual calculations, as they do work and get calculated if I add a Survey for the first Time , so the calculations are correct.
there is something wrong with the the SurveyDataResults entity since if done for the second time, gets detached even with different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error is certainly in the `CalculateServiceImpl` class, where you declare the `surveryresults` as a class member field. This is wrong to do in classes like services and repositories, you should try not to hold `state` information in such classes. This `surveyresults` once the service is instantiated (from Spring) is the same through all the calls to `CalculateXXX`, that's why you get the detached entity error.

```
SurveyDataResults surveyresults = new SurveyDataResults();
```

So remove this line from there, and load and work with `SurveyDataResults` from inside your `CalculateXXX` methods

An example can be the following, however I dont know if it will work as expected because you have not posted all your code (see my inline comment for example)

```
public void CalculateFirst(Long id){
    SurveyData survey = surveyDataRepository.findOne(id);
    Integer c=survey.getA()+survey.getB();
    SurveyDataResults  surveyResults = survey.getSurveyresults();
    if (surveyResults == null) {
        surveyResults = new SurveyDataResults();
        surveyResults.setSurvey(survey); //not present in your code but I assume it exists
    }
    surveyResults.setC(c);
    surveyServiceResults.saveSurveyResults(surveyresults);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Another point is the way you are saving the surveyResults, via the `SurveyDataResultsRepository`. If you do not set the `survey` via a setter method in `SurveyDataResults` like the one in my code example above, you have no relation of `SurveyData` and `SurveyDataResults`. If you don't have a `SurveyData` field inside the `SurveyDataResults` entity, then you should set the `SurveyDataResults` to `SurveyData` and save the `SurveyData` by calling the `SurveyDataRepository.save` and not via the `SurveyDataResultsRepository`.

e.g.

```
public void CalculateFirst(Long id){
    SurveyData survey = surveyDataRepository.findOne(id);
    Integer c=survey.getA()+survey.getB();
    SurveyDataResults  surveyResults = survey.getSurveyresults();
    if (surveyResults == null) {
        surveyResults = new SurveyDataResults();
        survey.setSurveyDataResults(surveyResults);
    }
    surveyResults.setC(c);
    surveyDataRepository.save(survey);
}
```